# How to be informed of state change cancellations in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

So I'm using UI-router in my application and im using the `$stateChangeStart` listener to show a loader and the `$stateChangeSuccess` to then hide the loader. This way I have a loader between state transitions.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
///show loader
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
                function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
//hide loader
});
```

Problem:

1. I'm in state A
2. I click on a button to go to state B, `$stateChangeStart` is called for B, my loader is shown.
3. Immediately I click on another button to go to state A (B has some stuff to *resolve*, so there's time before B's UI actually starts loading)
4. B is not loaded, and **`$stateChangeSuccess` is not called and my loader is never hidden** (Since we were already in A, it isn't reloaded)

So is there a way I can listen for state change cancellations and hide my loader?

Update: 
I created a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uf3nSuOIgd6zvpIniUUY?p=preview). In the plunk I've given a timeout of 10 seconds in B's resolve. So before it resolves, click on A. Monitor the console for state change listener events.

Update July 25, 2015 which uses latest AngularUI Router:
Created new [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YcuG5HCcCAYqdkapkSPY).

Comment: you can easily achieve this by maintaining state change information inside a service...

Comment: @entre But I won't know when a cancellation has occured.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the first Google result - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events ?

Comment: Did you even read my question? @PavelHoral

Comment: you dont know that cancellation happened, but you know that, another state-change-event has been fired..

Comment: I did read it and probably not understand where the problem is... there are some loader bar plugins, so you might want to check how they are doing it (e.g. ng-progress).

Comment: @entre Problem is state change start is fired, I show the loader, state change success is never fired where I hide the loader

Comment: And `$stateChangeError` is not fired as well? Because that was I referring to when I posted link to the documentation.

Comment: You can base it on a `resolve` like so - http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview

Comment: even if $stateChangeSuccess is not fired for one state, I am sure it will be fired for another state...

Comment: Neither $stateChangeSuccess nor $stateChangeError is fired

Comment: Can you construct [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), for example in JSBin or Plunker?

Comment: @PavelHoral, I have updated the question with the Plunker link.

Comment: You have error on line 17... nevertheless I see your issue and I am not sure how that should be handled. So +1 to give it possibly more attention.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, in exactly the same scenario. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2123) with the ui-router project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only sustainable solution I've found so far was to avoid using `ui-sref`. It masks the return value of `$state.go` which is key in this case.

The trick is to handle the `transition` promise returned by `$state.go`

```
$scope.safeGo = function(stateName){
  var transition = $state.go(stateName);
  transition.then(function(currentState){
    console.log('Transition finished successfully. State is ' + currentState.name);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    //revert your loader animation here
    console.log('Transition failed. State is ' + $state.current.name, err);
  })
}
```

The same object can be accessed via `$state.transition` property however between transitions the property is `null` and in any of the events that `$state` broadcasts it is also `null`. Thus the only solid option is to grab the return value of `$state.go`.

When state `A` is selected before `B` was resolved the `transition` promise for `B` will reject with a reason `Error: transition superseded`. However you will still have to wait until `B.resolve` is complete. If you want to avoid that you will have to keep track of your states on your own, since transition to `A` will be resolved immediately (because current state is still `A` while `B` is trying to resolve).

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bctQDA1BuN2ndcOF4IVL?p=info)